@solana/web3.js it is not possible to detect websocket error?
This code needs your API_KEY of HELIUM to be tested.
import { Connection, PublicKey } from '@solana/web3.js';
import { AccountLayout } from '@solana/spl-token';

// HELIUS
const RPC_URL:string = "https://mainnet.helius-rpc.com/?api-key=<YOUR_API_KEY>";  
const WSS_URL:string = "wss://mainnet.helius-rpc.com/?api-key=<YOUR_API_KEY>";  
const ACCOUNT_ADDR:PublicKey = new PublicKey("4sYhyij8KUo6FkgieXFXv2TjFj8QGiLMwD3YM7gmZ2mW");

const conn:Connection = new Connection(RPC_URL, {wsEndpoint: WSS_URL});
let id_conn:number=-1;

const subscribe = async ()=>{
    console.log('subscribe...');
    let conseguido:boolean = false;
    let intentos:number = 1;
    
    do{
        try{
           
            id_conn = conn.onAccountChange(
                ACCOUNT_ADDR,
                (accountInfo, context)=>{
                    let deserialized = AccountLayout.decode(accountInfo.data);
                    console.log(deserialized.amount);
                },
                "confirmed"
            ); 
            conseguido=true;     
            
           console.log(`conexion id: ${id_conn}`);

        }catch(e:any){
            **console.log('=> detectado error en subscribe');**
            console.log((e as Error).message);
            conseguido = false;
        }

        if(!conseguido){           
            console.log(`intento conexion: ${intentos}`);
            await delay(1000);
            intentos++;
        }else{
            console.log(`conseguida conexión`);
        }        

    }while(!conseguido);
    

}

const delay = async (ms:number):Promise<void> => new Promise(resolve=>setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const unsubscribe = async ()=>{

    console.log('unsubscribe...');
    let conseguido:boolean = false;
    let intentos:number = 1;

    do{
        try{
            await conn.removeAccountChangeListener(id_conn);
            conseguido=true;
        }catch(e:any){
            **console.log('=> detectado error en unsubscribe');**
            console.log((e as Error).message);
            conseguido = false;
        }

        if(!conseguido){           
            console.log(`intento desconexion: ${intentos}`);
            await delay(1000);
            intentos++;
        }else{
            console.log(`conseguida desconexión`);
        }

    }while(!conseguido);

}

(async ()=>{
    let vueltas:number = 1;
    while(1){
        console.log(`vuelta: ${vueltas}`);
        subscribe();
        await delay(5000);
        unsubscribe();
        await delay(5000);
        vueltas++;
    }
})();

This is the log:
vuelta: 1
subscribe...
conexion id: 0
conseguida conexión
27643029141447n
27643029141447n
27855302858635n
27855302858635n
27855302858635n
27855302858635n
27855302858635n
27855302858635n
27855302858635n
27855302858635n
unsubscribe...
conseguida desconexión
vuelta: 2
subscribe...       
conexion id: 1     
conseguida conexión
27873026408388n
27873026408388n
27942522316268n
===================================> TAKE OUT INTERNET !!!!!
unsubscribe...
vuelta: 3
subscribe...
conexion id: 2
conseguida conexión
unsubscribe...
conseguida desconexión
vuelta: 4
subscribe...
conexion id: 3
conseguida conexión
ws error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mainnet.helius-rpc.com
unsubscribe...
conseguida desconexión
ws error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mainnet.helius-rpc.com
ws error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mainnet.helius-rpc.com
ws error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mainnet.helius-rpc.com
ws error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mainnet.helius-rpc.com
ws error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mainnet.helius-rpc.com
vuelta: 5
subscribe...
conexion id: 4
conseguida conexión
ws error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mainnet.helius-rpc.com
ws error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mainnet.helius-rpc.com
ws error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mainnet.helius-rpc.com
ws error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mainnet.helius-rpc.com
ws error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mainnet.helius-rpc.com
unsubscribe...
conseguida desconexión
ws error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mainnet.helius-rpc.com
ws error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mainnet.helius-rpc.com
ws error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mainnet.helius-rpc.com
ws error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mainnet.helius-rpc.com
ws error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mainnet.helius-rpc.com
vuelta: 6
subscribe...
==========================>>> INTERNET ON AGAIN
conexion id: 5
conseguida conexión
ws error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mainnet.helius-rpc.com
28500064569870n
28500064569870n
28500064569870n
28500064569870n
28500064569870n
28451886219308n
unsubscribe...
conseguida desconexión
vuelta: 7
subscribe...
conexion id: 6
conseguida conexión
28514495008595n
28514495008595n

I can't see in the log:
=> detectado error en subscribe
=> detectado error en unsubscribe
Even when I see the error message "ws error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mainnet.helius-rpc.com" because I shut down internet connection, I can't detect the error with the try-catch block.
I posted this other question and someone suggeted me to try to detect the socket error with a try-catch block instead of check the socket status before trying to subscribe/unsubscribe.
Is it possible to detect this error or is it just a low level console.log that is not possible to detect?

This question is similar to: How to handle connection failures with "onLogs"?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

That question es quiet "open", and the answer is not "how to solve the problem with the current library" but "do the same thing with another library". I can try to change the library but I would like to know "why this is not working" and "what to do to make it work" with this library, no with another one (which I can try but it is not what I am asking).
